# MySQL LIKE statement inteprets "o" and "ö" as the same

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, collation

I have a Rails 3 application connected to a MySQL-database. The encoding used is utf-8. The database connects a lot of data in Swedish and has a search function.

When I search for `gotland` (a Swedish island) results for `Östergötland` (a shire) is returned as well. Apparently MySQL interprets `ö` as `o`.

Is there a simple way to make sure that `location LIKE '%gotland%'` does not return fields containing `götland`?

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that by adding `COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci` after the `LIKE` statement, you will get what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE name LIKE '%gotland%' COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Alternately, you might want to use `latin1_swedish_ci` if `latin1` is your character set.

I am not 100% certain that this fixes character comparison in a `LIKE` statement, but it logically should.

Sources:

- [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html)
- [Collation charts](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_swedish_ci.html)